# Drawing a graph in PyQt5, problem with loading data into a function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have some problem with drawing graphs using pyqtgraph in pyqt5. I have a function which from the set values in the QDoubleSpinBox fields is supposed to create a sine graph. I have checked and for manually entered values it draws the graph but does not draw it for values set in QDoubleSpinboxes. Thank you in advance for your help

```
import PyQt5
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from PyQt5 import uic


class App(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("layout.ui", self)
        self.title = "Generator Funkcji"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        save = QAction("Save", self)
        save.triggered.connect(self.save)

        exitProgram = QAction("Exit", self)
        exitProgram.triggered.connect(self.exit_program)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(save)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitProgram)

        # wartości do wykresu
        self.dsb_1 = self.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, "doubleSpinBox")
        self.dsb_1.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.dsb_1.valueChanged.connect(self.show_result)
        self.f = self.dsb_1.value()
        self.dsb_2 = self.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, "doubleSpinBox_2")
        self.dsb_2.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.A = self.dsb_2.value()
        self.dsb_3 = self.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, "doubleSpinBox_3")
        self.dsb_3.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.step = self.dsb_3.value()
        self.dsb_4 = self.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, "doubleSpinBox_4")
        self.dsb_4.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.range = self.dsb_4.value()

        self.t = np.linspace(0, int(self.step), int(self.step) * int(self.range))
        print(self.t)
        # wykres sinus
        self.sinus = self.findChild(QCheckBox, "checkBox")
        self.sinus.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.sine(self.f, self.A))

        # resetowanie wykresów
        self.btn_reset = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton")
        self.btn_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset)

        self.show()

    def show_result(self):
        value = self.dsb_1.value()
        return value

    def save(self):
        print('Zapisuje wynik działania do pliku')
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "", options=options)
        file = open(fileName, 'w')
        text = "Zawartość pliku"
        file.write(text)
        file.close()

    def exit_program(self):
        os._exit(0)

    def sine(self,f, A):
        self.graph = self.findChild(PlotWidget, "graphicsView")
        self.graph.setTitle('<font size=12>Sinus</font>')
        x = self.t
        y = A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x)
        self.plot = self.graph.plot(x, y)
        return self.plot

    def reset(self):
        self.plotWidget = self.graphicsView
        self.plotWidget.setTitle('')
        return self.plotWidget.clear()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `self.f` and `self.A` are set when the instance is created, and they will always have the initial value set in Designer. Change to `lambda: self.sine(self.dsb_1.value(), self.dsb_2.value())`. You also don't need to use `findChild`, as `loadUi` automatically creates instance attributes; you can access the spinboxes with `self.doubleSpinBox`, `self.doubleSpinBox_2`, etc.

Comment: @musicamante It still doesn't return any graph but it doesn't throw any errors so I think it gives zero values. In the console it prints out a value check for a given QDoubleSpinBox and returns me 0, I have no idea if this value doesn't renew itself when I type in a value and it stays 0

Comment: A signal connection doesn't return anything. Even if the function returns something, it's completely ignored. What I can see is that you're just creating a new plot in that function. Note that your usage of `self.t` there is again wrong, since you created it in the `__init__` (the same error you did above), so you need to compute it again. Your `show_result` is also wrong: `valueChanged` already provides the changed value, so you don't need to get it again; just change to `def show_result(self, value):` and you'll get it; as explained before, the return value is useless for signal connections.